# what happens when move an application to SD card

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-sdcard

android 2.2 introduce new feature that provide an ability to move an application to SD card or usb storage of phone.

[image: sample of move to SD]

i want to know what happens when a user choose "move to SD card" on android app info,

- what file's of application moves?
- where is moved files on SD card or where is new installation address?
- is there a way to handle what file's move and what files not move?
- how can i address new moved applications folder, for example database folder (before moving i can address it like "/data/data/APP_PACKAGE/databases/" )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android 2.2 introduce new feature that provide an ability to move an application to SD card or usb storage of phone

Note that this has been obsolete for years; you will not find this option on most Android 3.0+ devices.

> what file's of application moves?

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html):

> The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device memory.

> where is moved files on SD card or where is new installation address?

That is undocumented. Nothing that you access normally as a developer moves from wherever you accessed it before.

> is there a way to handle what file's move and what files not move?

No, other than to not move the app at all (e.g., `android:installLocation="internalOnly"`).

> how can i address new moved applications folder, for example database folder (before moving i can address it like "/data/data/APP_PACKAGE/databases/" )?

**NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**.

You can access the path to a database [via `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Move to SdCard is also available on Samsung Galaxy S4, android kitkat, not sure if this is samsung specific ?

Comment: @Ahmed: I cannot speak for the S4. However, Android M appears to be giving new life to `android:installLocation`, as users can "adopt" removable media to use for apps. So, while this was less relevant during the Android 3.0-5.1 timeframe, some manufacturers might have made it relevant (e.g., your S4), and it should become relevant for everyone running Android M and higher.